# How to transfer conversation to a new number?

Tags: contacts, chat-history

I have a contact who has a new phone number, so I update the old number with the new. But now when I check my sms conversations, I have 2 conversations: the "old" number conversation, and the "new" number conversation.

Is there a way to fix this ? 
I already tried to merge them and then delete the old one but the old one is still linked to that old phone number.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I think the solution is app dependant, so you should mention which phone and Android version you have if you're using the stock SMS app, or the name of the SMS app you're using.

Comment: Add both numbers to the same contact. Then it will display as one person. But as onik said it all depends on the app and so on.

Comment: I have a Sony Xperia U and I have the 4.04 android version, and I'm using the build-in SMS app.